# How can I get touch events from a TextView (Kotlin, Android)

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create an app where I have a TextView, which displays a number between 1 and 270.

There would be a variable that contains these values, from which i would later collect and convert to string to the TextView.

I would like to change the value of the variable by having a touch event in the TextView, which would give me the coordinates for the touching, and would scale the numbers up or down.

I can't find how do I attribute a touch event to my TextView. I just figured out how to create a onClick event, but I understand it doesn't have moving and all, just the first touch.

Comment: Hi, are you trying to track touch movement within the TextView? if so, have a look at the onTouchEvent.

Comment: Create a subclass of `TextView` and [override `onTouchEvent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View#ontouchevent).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding, there might be no need for a text view really, you may use a Text node instead or a label at worst.

but if its one number being displayed,where the textView would be, place the Text node with the value being changed by updating it through the GUI thread

if you want,you can have an up/down button to increase and/or decrease the value